# Two web applications with same Site Structure and Content can be work in one SharePoint Farm?

Tags: 2013, backup, restore

Hi i have scenario like below
I have a web application in Production SharePoint Farm it has custom master pages,many custom page layouts and angular .JS files and 
some farm solutions deployed target to this web application.

I have another web application (beta) in staging SharePoint Farm it is mounted to same content database  from production farm and in this web application i modified custom master pages and page layouts with new design and CSS.

Here in production i want to run two web applications in the same time
one is current production web application and second one is new web application mount to beta web application from staging.
for this requirement if i take backup of web-application from staging and restore to production farm can it be work ?
there are two web application can be work in same time or it face any conflicts in Site Collection ids and site ids?

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 site collections with same ID as long as they are in separate web applications.